# ParameterError when performing Audio noise reduction

Tags: python, scipy, noise-reduction

I have a project to create a noise reduction app in Python. I've searched many ways to solve this problem, but each example I've tried doesn't work, there are always some exceptions thrown.

I've tried this

```
import noisereduce as nr
from scipy.io import wavfile

rate, data = wavfile.read("input.wav")
noisy_part = data[10000:15000]
reduced_noise = nr.reduce_noise(audio_clip=data, noise_clip=noisy_part, verbose=True)
```

But I get this
[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
import soundfile as sf
data,rate=sf.read("input.wav")
```

it will work